# Saving a File on Android

Tags: java, android

I'm sure this has been asked hundreds of times, but I just can't point myself to the right direction.

I'm working on an app that after the first startup, generates an instance of a class that takes and saves user input. After that first startup, on every consecutive startup, I want to read that same instance, or at least load the same data from before into a new instance. How do I go about doing that?

From what I understand, I'll need to save this on a file generated on internal storage, but I'm not really sure. The data should expand as time passes, so I'm not sure how much big the data will become.

Thank you for any help.

EDIT: I think I'll expand a bit more on what I need...

Basically, I'm working on a small robot that takes user input and saves it in it's "brain". What I need to do is save this "brain" into a file, so that on each launch of the app, this "brain" is loaded. The user input will be nothing but strings.

Comment: [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) are better suited for this kind of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the Android [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) Class which is a which way to save setting between launches.

```
SharedPreferences appSettings = this.getSharedPreferences("fileName", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor = appSettings.edit;

appSettings_Edit.putString("saveme", "this will be saved"); //First Parameter, name of the value, second parameter, value of the name
appSettings_Edit.commit(); //This is called to commit the changes to memory.

//This can be called anytime after `commit()`, including in any sequential launches, and it will return the vale of whatever you set.
appSettings.getString("saveme");
```

If you want to save an actual `file` you can use a BufferedWriter to create some hard file on the system:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(fileName)));
out.write("I am a line of text written in" + fileName);
out.close();
```

You can then retrieve the contents of the file by using a BufferedReader:

```
List<String> SomeStringListArray = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
String s;
while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
    SomeStringListArray.add(s);
}
in.close();
```

You can also create this file in the Android Cache Directory so it will be accessable only by your file by having the path of the file name derived from:

```
this.getChachDir();
this.getExternalCacheDir();
```

Comment: The use of BufferedWriter seems like a good idea... Is there any limit on how the big the fie can be, or does that depend on the available memory allowed for the app? I'm thinking the data could reach sizes of 10+ megabytes.

Comment: I myself have not run into any problems with file size, however you will get to a point where it will take a long time to process depending on the file size and processing speed. I am not exactly sure if there s a file size limit. See my edit for retrieving data from the file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends somewhat on what sort of data you're collecting, but in general, using an [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) database will cover most needs.

If it's just a few values that the user can change, then [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

If object You want to save implements Serializable interface, You could save file using serialization. If You need code example, let me know. It's one of the easiest way.

Comment: Serialization is a bit of overhead just to store some simple data.

Comment: Agree. If we talk about saving primitives or String types - SharedPreferences are the best.

Answer (score 0):

Saving into a file is one possibility, but if the data would only be used by your application, you may want to consider other options...

If the data is pretty small, you can use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

For larger data, you can use a [`database`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

The different options you have (with some examples) are explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).